# parallel.foreach loop issue: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, linq, list, foreach, parallel.foreach

wanted to see if one of you guys could shed some light on this.
Getting an item with the same key has already been added Exception in below code:

```
foreach (EmailMessage m in findResultsSentItems)
{
    em.Add(m);
}
lstMailContactDeatils.Clear();
Parallel.ForEach(em,
        myItem =>
        {
            myItem.Load();
            foreach (EmailAddress e in myItem.ToRecipients)
            {
                try
                {
                    MailContactDeatils _MailContactDeatils1 = new MailContactDeatils();
                    _MailContactDeatils1.MailID = e.Address;
                    _MailContactDeatils1.DisplayName = e.Name;
                    _MailContactDeatils1.SentTime = myItem.DateTimeSent.ToString();
                //    if(lstMailContactDeatils.Contains())
                    lstMailContactDeatils.Add(_MailContactDeatils1);
                }
                catch (Exception e1) { exceptions.Enqueue(e1); }
            }
            foreach (EmailAddress e in myItem.CcRecipients)
            {
                try
                {
                    MailContactDeatils _MailContactDeatils2 = new MailContactDeatils();
                    _MailContactDeatils2.MailID = e.Address;
                    _MailContactDeatils2.DisplayName = e.Name;
                    _MailContactDeatils2.SentTime = myItem.DateTimeSent.ToString();
                    lstMailContactDeatils.Add(_MailContactDeatils2);
                }
                catch (Exception e2) { exceptions.Enqueue(e2); }
            }
        });
```

The LINQ statement is where I get an ArgumentExcpetion thrown saying: An item with the same key has already been added

Comment: Do you have custom equality comparison defined in MailContactDeatils?

Comment: What is `lstMailContactDeatils`?

Comment: lstMailContactDeatils is list of MailContactDeatils type.....
public class MailContactDeatils
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string MailID { get; set; }
        public string SentTime { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Your code doesn't show the parts that are essential here. How do you interact with the context? Anyway, you should never address one context instance from multiple threads. Which means: replace the `Parallel.ForEach` by plain `foreach`.

Comment: but i am using Parallel.ForEach to improver performance of service.... it takes more than 5 minutes to read 500 mails by using  plain foreach because it runs on single thread.

Comment: If it takes *that* long to read 500 records, your problem is somewhere else. Don't try to fix poor queries by parallelization.

Comment: One obvious improvement would be to load all items at once.

Comment: use ConcurrentDictionary and its GetOrAdd method.

Comment: none of the answers helped?

Answer (score 0):

As you're using `Parallel` you will need to lock before adding.

```
object padlock = new object();

foreach (EmailMessage m in findResultsSentItems)
{
    em.Add(m);
}
lstMailContactDeatils.Clear();
Parallel.ForEach(em,
        myItem =>
        {
            myItem.Load();
            foreach (EmailAddress e in myItem.ToRecipients)
            {
                try
                {
                    MailContactDeatils _MailContactDeatils1 = new MailContactDeatils();
                    _MailContactDeatils1.MailID = e.Address;
                    _MailContactDeatils1.DisplayName = e.Name;
                    _MailContactDeatils1.SentTime = myItem.DateTimeSent.ToString();

                    lock(padlock) {
                        if(!lstMailContactDeatils.Contains(_MailContactDeatils1))
                            lstMailContactDeatils.Add(_MailContactDeatils1);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e1) { exceptions.Enqueue(e1); }
            }
            foreach (EmailAddress e in myItem.CcRecipients)
            {
                try
                {
                    MailContactDeatils _MailContactDeatils2 = new MailContactDeatils();
                    _MailContactDeatils2.MailID = e.Address;
                    _MailContactDeatils2.DisplayName = e.Name;
                    _MailContactDeatils2.SentTime = myItem.DateTimeSent.ToString();
                    lock(padlock) {
                        if (!lstMailContactDeatils.Contains(_MailContactDeatils2))
                            lstMailContactDeatils.Add(_MailContactDeatils2);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e2) { exceptions.Enqueue(e2); }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Still got Exception: An item with the same key has already been added... Exception occurs randomly, like 2 out of 6 times while running the code

Comment: Is it throwing on the first foreach loop or the second one ?

Comment: This lock practically defeats the purpose of parallel processing. But OP shouldn't use a parallel loop anyway (see above).

Comment: I don't know in which loop error occurs, not able to debug Parallel.ForEach as it whole code consider as single statement.... i am using parallel processing to improve performance.

Comment: @GertArnold, I disagree. Only a small part of the forloop is locked.

Comment: Yeah, the parts not benefiting from parallel processing. The interactions with the context are relatively slow, esp. when they trigger database queries. These interactions must not be parallelized.

Comment: Any other solution Guys...???? still getting exception.... after apply check  if(!lstMailContactDeatils.Contains(_MailContactDeatils1))

Comment: My advice is below your question.